# REact error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am trying to login into my app. But I get an error saying: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
I can login but i don't want to clean this error. Thanks for you help
[image]

Component Myapp

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
import client from '../config/apollo'
import StateOrder from '../Context/Orders/StateOrder'
import '../styles.css'
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <StateOrder>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </StateOrder>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
export default MyApp
```

Component index

```
import Layout from '../Components/Layout'
import Client from '../Components/Client'
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Link from 'next/link'

const GET_CLIENTS_BY_USER = gql`
query getClientsBySalesman{
  getClientsBySalesman{
    id
    name
    surname
    company
    email
  }
}`

const Index = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CLIENTS_BY_USER)

  if (loading) return <p className="my-2 bg-blue-100 border-l-4 border-blue-700 p-4 text-center">Carregant...</p>

  if (error || !data.getClientsBySalesman) {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    return router.push('/login')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <h1 className="text-2xl text-gray-800">Clients</h1>
        <Link href="/nouclient">
          <a className="bg-blue-800 py-2 px-5 mt-3 inline-block text-white rounded text-sm hover:bg-gray-800 uppercase w-full lg:w-auto text-center">Nou Client</a>
        </Link>
        <div className="sm:overflow-x-scroll">
          <table className="table-auto shadow-md mt-10 w-full w-lg">
            <thead className="bg-gray-800">
              <tr className="text-white">
                <th className="w-1/5 py-2">Nom</th>
                <th className="w-1/5 py-2">Empresa</th>
                <th className="w-1/5 py-2">Email</th>
                <th className="w-1/5 py-2">Eliminar</th>
                <th className="w-1/5 py-2">Editar</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className="bg-white">
              {data.getClientsBySalesman.map(client => (
                <Client
                  key={client.id}
                  client={client} />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </div >
  )
}
export default Index
```

Component StateOrder

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import ContextOrder from './ContextOrder'
import ReducerOrder from './ReducerOrder'

import {
  SELECT_CLIENT,
  SELECT_PRODUCT,
  PRODUCT_QUANTITY,
  UPDATE_TOTAL
} from '../../types'

const StateOrder = ({ children }) => {
  const initialState = {
    client: {},
    products: [],
    total: 0
  }
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ReducerOrder, initialState)
  const addClient = client => {
    dispatch({
      type: SELECT_CLIENT,
      payload: client
    })
  }

  const addProduct = selectProducts => {
    let newState
    if (state.products.length > 0) {
      newState = selectProducts.map(product => {

        const newObject = state.products.find(productState => productState.id === product.id);
        return { ...product, ...newObject }
      })
    } else {
      newState = selectProducts;
    }
    dispatch({
      type: SELECT_PRODUCT,
      payload: newState
    })
  }

  const productQuantity = newProduct => {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_QUANTITY,
      payload: newProduct
    })
  }

  const updateTotalOrder = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_TOTAL
    })

  }
  return (
    <ContextOrder.Provider
      value={{
        client: state.client,
        products: state.products,
        total: state.total,
        addClient,
        addProduct,
        productQuantity,
        updateTotalOrder
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ContextOrder.Provider>
  )
}
export default StateOrder
```

Comment: It's the `return router.push('/login')` that's causing your issue, get rid of the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, I had the same mistake and it worked for me. What I understand is that when you return the `router.push('/login')` the default router of next.js calls a promise and so the exception is generated.

```
if (!data.getClientsBySalesman) {
    window.location.href = 'login';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Component named ***Index*** you are checking for error and if it exists you'd want the URL to be changed to "/login" which is correct, but instead of doing this, you are returning router.push() value.

```
if (error || !data.getClientsBySalesman) {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    return router.push('/login')
}
```

Since this is a functional component, as soon as React encounters this return statement in case there is an error, React assumes this return value is what you'd like to render. But since you can not just render objects. React gives you the error about invalid child being present in render.

Comment: If I understand I have to remove the return. But if I remove the return, I can change de url but it doesn't redirect to the login component and the app break

Comment: That's strange, it shouldn't happen, can you help me with a codesandbox link for the above sample. Omitting that return statement should not break anything. It is very unlikely to cause an error. On a side note, you might try to change the window URL without using the router object. See if that works. Although it would not be the ideal way to handle it.

Comment: front codesanbox : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/carmecass/test-CRM/tree/master/crm-client
back codesandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/carmecass/test-CRM/tree/master/crm-api

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the **return** keyword and it will work without throwing an error:

```
 if (error || !data.getClientsBySalesman) {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    router.push('/login')
  }
```